# PhpStorm array indentation 8 spaces in stead of 4

Tags: php, phpstorm

The code style in PhpStorm has been doing strange things to my array indentation.
When creating a new array in a normal way

```
$array = [|] // The | marks my cursor
```

Then I press enter

```
$array = [
        | // My cursor starts all the way there
]
```

When I reformat my code using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, the indentation is reset.

```
$array = [
    | // To here
]
```

This happens in every file in my project. I have checked my code style preferences, I have set them to PSR1/PSR2 standard, and have checked every single option that has something to do with indentation/arrays.

This only happens to arrays, not to function declarations, class declarations and control structures.

Is anyone familiar with this problem and if so, is there a solution?

Comment: Doesn't PHP storm have settings for different types?

Comment: How about to send a bug report to jetbrains ;-)

Comment: @Niek What do you mean, exactly? I have checked all code style PHP settings, but I can't find anything that would cause this behaviour.

Comment: `Settings->CodeStyle->PHP->Tabes and Indent` There are schemes for `default` and `project` check them all.

Comment: I have, they are all set to 4 spaces, tab size, indent, and continuation indent. I have just found out that upon creating a new file, this behaviour does not appear. I have also already disabled `Detect and use existing file indents for editing`.

Comment: In case someone get here searching for a very similar bug that happen only in executable PHP files (read: with shebang) and not only affects array declarations but also function calls, etc., see this bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36265

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Yeah, 2021 and we are still here with annoying formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1.Go to Preferences -> Code Style -> PHP -> Set from... -> Predefined Style -> allows you to set your code style guidelines to the styles such as PSR-2 and Zend.

2.Go to Code -> Reformat Code -> This option will format all of your code to the code style you set. We recently converted our codebase of around 300,000 lines to the PSR-2 standard. It was done in less than 5 minutes.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have reformatted all code in my project, with PSR-2 standards enabled. The problem still persists though, in some files arrays just indent with 8 spaces. If I then reformat the code, it returns to a 4-space indentation. But a new array will be indented with 8 spaces again.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Connor.

Answer (score 2):

If your file has mixed PHP/HTML content, check your HTML continuation indent under
**Editor -> Code Style -> HTML -> Tabs and Indents.**

Unlike with PHP, it defaults to 8 instead of 4. Change **continuation indent** to 4, then it will be alright. I changed mine to 4 and now my array declarations look right.

Answer (score 0):

This option is located here:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP
```

Option name:

```
Continuation indent:
```

And change from `8` to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you face the same problem. Make sure to disable your `.editorconfig` rules as those might conflict with your Predefined Style rules. At `Editor > Code Style > EditorConfig`, scroll at the bottom and uncheck `Enable EditorConfig support`.